# Make Navbar Active Link Background Color Remains Highlighted

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, navbar

I have code for side bar. I want the background of the link changes when I click it (background color automatically changes when I click either pegawai or absen). But with the javascript code like that, it always loading and the background color can't stay focused. How do I make background color for active bars?

[image: script for the active link]

[image: code for link]

Answer (score 0):

It's not that simple because css can't retain the style if it's not initial style.
You need to adjust your jQuery code to check the url of the page also. You can utilize `window.location.pathname`
And check if the current path name match with any link and add the css there.